# MODBUS device register definitions

Tags: industry

MODBUS is a common and widely used protocol in industrial applications for connection sensors, plc's and machines. When accessing MODBUS devices the core are register definitions. These vary from device to device, even if the devices are from the same manufacturer.

I am looking for a global directory of register definitions for MODBUS devices.